# Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, game-systems

As I brought up in the comments of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131757/33569), it would be great if it were possible to somehow have a specified tag always be listed first on a post, or if certain special tags (in RPG.SE's case, system tags) always appeared first when applied to any post.

As SevenSidedDie pointed out in a comment there, adding any tag to a post that's more popular than the system tag:

> demotes the system from the first tag spot, thus removing it from the page title and some Google searches.

This is obviously not ideal, hence my suggestion.

**Please add a checkbox to the Tag Info page for moderators to mark a tag as "special", so that it is always sorted to be first on a post.** (I imagine such a feature would be useful network-wide, but especially on RPG.SE.)

This would work like the four special tags on meta: all special tags are sorted by popularity first, then all normal tags are sorted by popularity.

Comment: I revised it a bit to make it more a request than a question, and added a bit about how (I imagine) the feature could work. How does that look?

Comment: Looks good! Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is a feature I’d ***love*** to see, as it would be super effective at RPG.se. I’m dubious SE would implement it, but here’s hoping!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I could see it being useful on the main SE, where the language the question would benefit from being first, but for less common languages might be pushed behind language-agnostic tags.

Comment: I will note that Meta sites seem to already have a similar feature, as the "must choose at least one" tags like [tag:feature-request] and [tag:discussion] always appear first. That doesn't necessarily make it any easier or more likely to happen on the normal sites, but it seems to at least be possible.

Comment: Related feature request (and maybe good to roll together if implementing): [Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and "more meaningful"?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8702/321)

Comment: Related 2011 meta from the Arqade, with a (disappointing) reply by Jeff Atwood: [Make a special tag class for “game tags”.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/make-a-special-tag-class-for-game-tags)

Comment: I've added the [status-review] tag, per this MSE post: [Community and Moderator guidelines for escalating issues via new response process (March 2020)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345032/community-and-moderator-guidelines-for-escalating-issues-via-new-response-proces)

Answer (score 5):

You make a good point regarding Google ranking. I imagine that is frustrating when you're looking for a particular answer. Thanks for putting so much thought into this.

Based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we are planning to take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future.