# Tags eclipsing system tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

This question recently had the "firearms" tag added to it:

[What's the expected benefit of the second pistol?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119958/whats-the-expected-benefit-of-the-second-pistol)

I don't object, but now it shows up as the first tag, and the title (in the window and, IIRC, in digests) is "Firearms - What's the expected benefit of the second pistol?"

This is a lot less useful than having one the system tags in front, given that it's a *highly* system-specific question.

I've tried reordering the tags but the system seems to automatically put the biggest tag first. Is there a fix for this besides "ask 50 more S&V questions" or "remove the least useful tag?"

Comment: Related feature request (by me): [Make it possible for certain tags (like game tags) to always appear first](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8366/make-it-possible-for-certain-tags-like-game-tags-to-always-appear-first). And another by Glazius: [Can we color system tags to emphasize that they're different and “more meaningful”?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8702/can-we-color-system-tags-to-emphasize-that-theyre-different-and-more-meaningfu)

Answer (score 11):

Don't try to manage the tag featured in the page title, or which tag comes first.

We can't manage those very well and they will usually be a bit wrong or weird. Finagling the tags to try to make sure the right one will show up where you want it will in all likelihood wind up making the question itself worse somehow.

Just apply the tags, let the system do its thing and if it picks the wrong tag to emphasise, let it be and move on to other things.

In an ideal world we'd be able to pick a primary tag or pin system tags to the start, but we can't, and we shouldn't try to do workarounds on it.

Comment: I mean, the spirit of my question is that I may well want to remove a cross-system category tag if I think it's not doing anything useful for the question.

Comment: I hear you. The firearms tag seems to fit, but is also fine not being on the question — but it fitting means someone else will likely come by to add it anyway. Adding/removing tags for the sake of the page title is just something I suggest you flat-out don't do: you can't and won't be able to manage the page title properly. Don't let yourself get into the habit of worrying about it or trying to fix it. It will be silly or seem wrong most of the time on most systems' questions.

Answer (score 4):

There is a possible workaround which is including the tag in the title. Looking at this [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72692/which-tag-is-added-to-the-page-title), it seems that one of the two most popular tags is used in the page title. If one of them is part of the question title, the other one is used in the page.

I tried editing the question to title to "What's the benefit of using two **firearms**?" and indeed the displayed page title was changed to ""blades in the dark - What's the benefit of using two firearms?"

Naturally this isn't a perfect solution but at least in this particular question it seems good enough (assuming this question title or a similar one with the word "firearms" is ok) and something useful to keep in mind

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can exclude a tag from being in the page title by including it in the question title ?

Comment: @PierreCathé That is how it works, yes though I don't know what happens if you include both top 2 tags

Comment: "What's the benefit of using two firearms?" sounds quite different. "Using two firearms" is shooting with two guns, but the author asks about "the second pistol" in the loadout specifically, not about using two firearms simultaneously: "what's the benefit of checking 2 load boxes to bring two handguns on a job"

Comment: @enkryptor That's ok, the main point of the meta answer was not the specific edit itself but the fact that including the word "firearms" in the question would allow another tag to be visible. If another more suitable question title that includes "firearms" were to be proposed that would be ideal